# ERC20 token scam

Tags: erc-20, contract-debugging, scam

I'm curious to know if there are tools that can detect scam by directly analyzing the smartcontract of the ERC 20 token? How do tools like tokensniffer work?

Comment: The tokensniffer website shows why the contract is determined to be fake. It seems to be a combination of several factors like supply, holders, liquidity, comparison with other well known scam contracts, and some third parties providers that audit contracts.